# create http server in react native with react-native-http-bridge

Tags: react-native, httpserver

I am going to create an http server using react native whose job is to respond to a number of APIs. From my research I found that this can be done using two packages [react-native-http-bridge](https://github.com/voxtok/react-native-http-bridge) and [react-native-http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-http-server). After installing these packages and linking them to the program (both automatic and manual) and starting the program, I encounter the following error. Please guide me if you know a solution to this problem or there are other solutions to implement what I want to do.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make this change in react-native-http-bridge/android/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
    -compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:+'
    +compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.1.0'
    compile 'org.nanohttpd:nanohttpd:2.3.1'
}
```

Take a look here: https://github.com/alwx/react-native-http-bridge/commit/a6c2c705561250198fc601a92b0d2579ec50fe11